# Open question - approach to node classification in a directed multi-relational graph

Tags: classification, graph-neural-network, knowledge-graph

The problem in hand is: **In a strategy game, I need to select characters to form my team, in order to win against a second team, chosen by an opponent player.** The universe of characters contains U characters, but we, both the opponent and I, select only from a subset Us of characters. I need to select M characters for my team. I may select the same character more than once. The characters possess inherent abilities, like “strength”, but they also display abilities which result in possible synergies, like “can heal”, “can drill holes” or “can hide in holes” (for example, a character that drills holes might be useful with another that hides in holes).

I thought of modeling this as a directed multi-relational graph, in which nodes might be characters or the objects they can act upon and edges describe the actions. In the example above, “can heal” would be modeled as JOHN(node of type “character”) --heals(edge)→ CHARACTER(node of type “category”). In the graph of the subset Us, the node CHARACTER would have an edge(category_of) pointing to every node of type “character”, describing the synergy John can have with other characters of the subset.
The data I have available consists of many examples of team compositions (which characters are included in the team and how many times) and their success rate in a given subset Us.

The approach I am designing would consist of the following steps:

1. **Build static features of character nodes.** Static features are features independent of the full graph of Us.
2. **Build static features of edges.** These could be built once for the whole universe U of characters.
3. **Train a model to predict how many times a character should appear in the team.** I thought of something along the lines of what is described in this paper. It would mean doing an entity classification for the character nodes. The input being examples of subset Us_x and the target being the team composition in this subset.
4. **Apply the model to a new subset Us_new to get a prediction of a team.**

I am posting this here to get feedback on this approach. All opinions are appreciated. For example:

1. Do you see any obvious flaws or caveats?
2. Has anybody tried something similar or had a similar problem?
3. Do you know of any implementation similar to this that I could bootstrap?
4. Do you know of other relevant papers that might be helpful?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.